# Selenium for WORD plugin

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, plugins, automated-tests

I have a plugin that I developed for Microsoft WORD.
I need to write automation tests on it to test it.
Can I use Selenium to write the tests? If so, how?
And if Selenium does not support such tests, is there a tool for automation tests that does?
I would appreciate advice on how to test this plugin (preferably with Selenium - Python).

Answer (score 1):

Selenium by itself is **not** able to automate anything outside of a web browser.

But there are options:

1. You might try [Winium](https://github.com/2gis/Winium.Desktop/blob/master/README.md) - automation tool for windows based on Selenium.

Following is example code found here:

```
package com.tests;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.DesktopOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver;

public class Tests 
{
    @Test
    public void CalcTest() throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException
    {

        DesktopOptions option = new DesktopOptions();
        option.setApplicationPath("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\WINWORD.EXE");

        WiniumDriver driver = new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), option);
        //Sleep is to wait until the word becomes visible
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("Blank document")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("Insert")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("Shapes")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("Rectangle")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("Page 1")).click();
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

This is in Java, but you can use Python, as well.

2. [pywinauto](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

> pywinauto is a set of python modules to automate the Microsoft Windows GUI. At its simplest it allows you to send mouse and keyboard actions to windows dialogs and controls.